# error while connecting to server through jsch com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException

Tags: java, jsch

By jcraft i have been connecting to server since years perfectly but suddenly i got session is down can some body help me on this?
what might be the reason for this?

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: session is down
```

Comment: Did your server change the ssl algorithm or compression type  ?

Comment: Hi,Due to rekey generation for sftp the session got crashed. this is a bug in  jsch jar old versions.this bug was fixed in jsch-0.1.52. and by this the issue got resolved. but my question is why it didn't happen these many years..? 
for your question: how can i know whether ssl algorithm changed in server?